# Comparing Event Actions

Tags: google-analytics

I have an event that has two different actions. I would like to compare the actions to get stats. I am struggling on how to set this up in Google Analytics (custom reports).

Here is how I would like the table set up:

> (rows) Event Label - Name of page
>   (column 1) Event Action - Page View (total # of events with this
>   action)
>   (column 2) Event Action - Form Submission (total # of events with this
>   action)

(they share the same event category)

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensions : Event Label , Event Action
Metrics    : Total (Unique?) Events

Filter : Event Action Regex => Page View|Form Submission

Comment: No problem mate